# html - use onsubmit and action together

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want the form to post the credentials via a get request but have difficulties making it work together with the onsubmit parameter which is used to validate the data entered. This is my form code:

```
<form onsubmit="return formValidation()" action="show_get.php" method="get" name="registration">
```

This is the code I used for validation

```
function formValidation() {
    var name = document.registration.name;
    var uemail = document.registration.email;
    {
        if (allLetter(name)) {
            if (ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                if (checkDate()) {
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function allLetter(name) {
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (name.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Name must have alphabet characters only');

        return false;
    }
}

function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");

        return false;
    }
}

function checkDate() {
    var selectedText = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
    var now = new Date();
    if (selectedDate < now) {
        alert("Date must be in the future");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach an `onsubmit` event handler and it returns `false`, the form will not be submitted. In your case, that *always* happens, even if the input is valid.

You check `allLetter()`, then `ValidateEmail()` and `checkDate()`, but you don't return `true` when they're all valid. Your code continues and it reaches `return false;`. The `submit` event handler returns the result of that validation function (which is `false`), so **it** returns `false` too. This tells the form to **not** submit.

Change your validation function to this:

```
function formValidation() {
  var name = document.registration.name;
  var uemail = document.registration.email;

  if (allLetter(name) && ValidateEmail(uemail) && checkDate()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If all three checks return `true`, the validation function will return `true` as well and the form will be submitted.

**Note:** You had one unnecessary pair of brackets (`{}`), I removed them. I also improved readability by combining all the nested `if` statements into one.

---

**Edit:** Also, your `checkDate()` doesn't return `true` and `false` accordingly. It returns `undefined` by default, which is a falsy value. This means that it won't pass the validation function's `&&` check and the form won't get submitted. Change `checkDate()` to this:

```
function checkDate() {
  var selectedText = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
  var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
  var now = new Date();
  if (selectedDate < now) {
    alert("Date must be in the future");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** You also incorrectly get the values of your input elements. When you do this:

```
var name = document.registration.name;
var uemail = document.registration.email;
```

You get the HTML **element** with name attribute `name` and HTML **element** with name attribute `email`. You should get the elements' values:

```
var name = document.registration.name.value;
var uemail = document.registration.email.value;
```

**It's best to edit your answer and add the full HTML and JavaScript. There might be more problems.**